# Create multiple records automatically in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way for postgres to automatically generate child records with set parameters? I'm basically trying to create an employee timesheet and each time a new timesheet for a given date is created, I'd like to create a 7 child records (one record for each day of that given week for the user to fill in)
Something like this:

```
date (automatically generated on a weekly basis)  | hours | timesheet_id(FK) | project_id(FK)
2019-01-01                                           8            1                  2
2019-01-02                                           10           1                  2
2019-01-03                                           8            1                  2
2019-01-04                                           8            1                  2
2019-01-05                                           0            1                  2
2019-01-06                                           0            1                  2
2019-01-07                                           9            1                  2
```

Comment: You can do that with a trigger

Comment: What would it look like

Answer (score 1):

@Z4-tier is correct but the trigger function does not need a loop as it can be reduced to a single insert statement.

```
create or replace function create_timesheet_days()
returns trigger 
language 'plpgsql'
as $$ 
begin 

    insert into timesheet_days(timesheet_id, week_day) 
      select new.timesheet_id, wk_day
        from generate_series (new.timesheet_date, new.timesheet_date+interval '6 day', interval '1 day') wk_day; 

    return new; 
end; 
$$ ;
```

Comment: Curious if you profiled this. I'm sure it is more efficient but at some level it must still be looping, so how much of an efficiency gain is there?

Comment: @Z4-tier. I did not profile this one specifically. Further processing just 6 rows I am sure the gain in not much. However, SQL is a set based language and looping structures processing a single row is often referred to as "slow-by-slow" processing (coined Tom Kyte of Oracle see  AskTom.com). Typically, converting from a loop structure to set processing gains at least an order of magnitude often several. Scan the answers on SO and see how many suggest abandoning looping for single statements.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in the comments, this is a textbook case for using triggers.

You'll need a procedure that handles creating the new records. This might work:

```
create or replace function create_timesheet_days()
returns trigger as $BODY$ 
declare counter INTEGER := 0; 
begin 
  while counter < 6 loop 
    insert into my_schema.timesheet_week
      (timesheet_date, hrs, timesheet_id, project_id) 
      select 
        NEW.timesheet_date + counter as timesheet_date, 
        0 as hrs, 
        NEW.timesheet_id as timesheet_id, 
      project.project_id as project_id
    from my_schema.project; 
    counter := counter + 1; 
  end loop; 
return NEW; 
END; 
$BODY$ 
language 'plpgsql';
```

Then you could create a trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER create_timsheet_days_trigger
BEFORE INSERT
ON my_schema.timesheet_week
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE
create_timesheet_days();
```